# How to filter condition not existed in IN list value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given that I have and a table **country**, which has column **name** to store name of a country.

```
Table schema: 
Column Name | Datatype     | Description
ID          | int          | ID of the table
name        | varchar(255) | Name of the country, i.e: UK, US, China
```

Now if I have a list of n string values as input data to filter:

```
i.e: Tokyo, Japan, US, New York, UK, London, India, China, etc
```

How can I write a sql query to filter all the values which doesn't exist in country table

```
i.e: I want to return Tokyo, NewYork, London.
```

Comment: but Tokyo, NewYork, London exists in your country table.

Comment: No. Country table only store country name (UK, US, China,etc) not city

Comment: Your DMBS cannot be both mysql and postgresql at the same time. Which one is it ?

Comment: I used Postgres Database

Comment: Put another way you are pulling out cities (and misspelled countries) from a csv string on the basis that they don't exist in country?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in Postgres:

```
select d.name from unnest(array['Japan', 'US', 'New York', 'UK', 'London', 'India', 'China']) d(name)
 left join country on country.name=d.name where country.name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you need to filter column name, i am not tested this yet but give it a try (MySQL):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'country' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('your_list_values')
```

I might misunderstanding your question, you should post your country table schema for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your input (Tokyo, Japan, US, New York, UK, London, India, China) into a table. Something like this

```
With CTE AS (
SELECT 'Tokyo' as name UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Japan' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'US' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'New York' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'UK' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'London' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'India' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'China' 
)
select name from CTE 
LEFT JOIN country ON CTE.name=country.name
WHERE country.name is NULL
```